# Execute multiple statements in the query editor

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to execute two statements using the **Query Editor**. One to set the parameter `search_path` and another to run a query against PG_TABLE_DEF.
I need to submit both queries at once because  the `set` statement seems to have no affect on subsequent queries.

```
set search_path to '$user', 'public', 'demo';
select * from pg_table_def where tablename = 'demotable';
```

However only the results for the first statement are returned.

Is there any way to return the results of the second statement?

Note: I cant change the users default search path or make any other changes to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say query editor, you mean in the Redshift console UI?

If so, then as far as I know, it can only execute a single query, and when you have multiple queries, as you do here, only the first is executed.

The new (not so new now - in fact, I recall the original UI has now finally been permanently disabled, which sucks) UI has a lot of issues.  This may or may not be one of them - you could I think argue for it on the basis of a design decision - it's certainly a restriction.

Comment: exactly, I mean the Redshift console UI. I take this as the answer because now I doubt that there is a workaround despite not using the UI.

Answer (score 2):

With "Query editor v2", multiple result tabs show up, one for each query output.

For your 2 queries there will be 'Result 1' and 'Result 2' output tabs.